# CPUminer config file faulty

Tags: shell, compilation, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to compile my CPUminer (linux/raspbian) and I'm getting the following error:

```
./configure: line 5688: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
./configure: line 5688: `LIBCURL_CHECK_CONFIG(, 7.15.2, , AC_MSG_ERROR([Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2]))'
```

the line in the config file:

```
LIBCURL_CHECK_CONFIG(, 7.15.2, , AC_MSG_ERROR([Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2]))
```

filling up the blank entries like `LIBCURL_CHECK_CONFIG(0, 7.15.2, 0, AC_MSG_ERROR([Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2]))` doesn't work...

is also not workint

maybe an error before this line:

```
if test x$request_jansson = xtrue
then
    JANSSON_LIBS="compat/jansson/libjansson.a"
else
    JANSSON_LIBS=-ljansson
fi
# line 5687
LIBCURL_CHECK_CONFIG(, 7.15.2, , AC_MSG_ERROR([Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2]))

ac_config_files="$ac_config_files Makefile compat/Makefile compat/jansson/Makefile"
```

as I have absolutely no knowledge about shell scripts I don't know where the error is.

Any help would be very appreciated...

Comment: Did you install `libcurl` on your system? Seems to me that this lib is missing hence the error.

Comment: I installed libcurl4 but I can re-install it.. Could it be an issue that I didn't restart my pi after the installation?

Comment: No, restarting shouldn't be necessary. You might need to run `ldconfig`.

Comment: Also check that the version of libcurl you have is >= 7.15.2.

Comment: Nope didn't work... But when I run sudo apt-get liburl liburl4 I get an error: unable to locate package liburl same for liburl4

Comment: `libcurl`, not `liburl` ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Sorry... I was clicking on the wrong button... Wanted to comment but accidentally answered.. I have solved the problem now by doing apt get upgrade and update and reinstalling everything... It's working(mining) now :)

Comment: Great! Happy it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  tried  `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update` and I reinstalled everything.

Somehow it's working now!